# Sutta References on Future Monks

Tags: pali-canon, sutras, monk

I have heard that the Buddha has told that in the future the monks will have a wife and kids, will wear no cloths except for a puuna nula and he would be engaging in hunting and etc.

Where can I find the Sutta of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the future, Ananda, there will be clan-members [(religious) lineage members] who are **“yellow-necks,”** immoral, of bad nature. People will give them gifts for the sake of the sangha. Even then, Ānanda, I say, an offering made to the sangha is immeasurable. And, Ānanda, I say that in no way is an individual gift ever more fruitful than an offering made to the sangha.

[Dakkhiṇa Vibhaṅga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.9-Dakkhina-Vibhanga-S-m142.pdf)

Comment: I'm interested to read this Sutta, but the link is broken, could u help? @Suminda

Comment: Update the link.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210506195537/http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.9-Dakkhina-Vibhanga-S-m142.pdf